# Swift5 MacOS ImageResize memory issue

Tags: swift, macos, image, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am new to Mac OS App Development with Swift. But I tried to make the simple ImageResizer app. I have to resize 50k images. After 10 hours, the memory has increased to nealy 120GB. I thought Swift also has Garbage collector. Why does it increase memory? I will show you my code.

```
for i in 0..<paths.count {
    let path = paths[i]

    if let image = NSImage(contentsOf: path) {
        ...

        if self.resize(image: image, size: size, to: URL(fileURLWithPath: resizedImagePath)) {
            print("Image saved to \(resizedImagePath)")
            continue
        }
    }
}

func resize(image: NSImage, size: Int, to url: URL) -> Bool {
    if !image.isValid {
        print("invalid image")
        return false
    }

    guard let pixelsWide = image.representations.first?.pixelsWide else {
        return false
    }

    let factor: CGFloat = CGFloat(pixelsWide) / image.size.width

    var width: CGFloat = CGFloat(size)
    var height: CGFloat = CGFloat(size)
    if image.size.width > image.size.height {
        height = width * image.size.height / image.size.width
    } else {
        width = height * image.size.width / image.size.height
    }

    let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
                               pixelsWide: Int(width),
                               pixelsHigh: Int(height),
                               bitsPerSample: 8,
                               samplesPerPixel: 4,
                               hasAlpha: true,
                               isPlanar: false,
                               colorSpaceName: .deviceRGB,
                               bytesPerRow: Int(width * 4),
                               bitsPerPixel: 32)
    rep?.size = NSSize(width: width / factor, height: height / factor)

    let ctx = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: rep!)
    NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
    NSGraphicsContext.current = ctx
    image.draw(in: NSMakeRect(0, 0, width / factor, height / factor))
    ctx?.flushGraphics()
    NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()

    // Get NSData, and save it
    let data = rep?.representation(using: .png, properties: [:]) // properties as! [String : Any]) //
    do {
        try data?.write(to: url)
        return true
    }
    catch {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your whole code  that it is inside your loop inside an [autoreleasepool](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html):

> If you write a loop that creates many temporary objects. You may use
>   an autorelease pool block inside the loop to dispose of those objects
>   before the next iteration. Using an autorelease pool block in the loop
>   helps to reduce the maximum memory footprint of the application.

```
for i in paths.indices {
    autoreleasepool {
        // all your image resizing code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift uses ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) which means objects will be deallocated when the number of strong references to that object reaches zero. I don't immediately see in the code provided where the problem is, but I suspect there must be some location elsewhere in your code where you are holding a reference to the images.

Comment: It does not have other code that can increase memory. Other code is just getting the destination path. And if I remove the code provided, then it takes less than 1 sec and does not increase memory.