# PHImageManager.default().requestImage() make memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

If i want to convert array **PHAsset to UIImage(count > 100)**, i have **memory error** and my app crash(i use 1,9gb memory).

How can i **improve** this situation?

My code:

```
func getAssetThumbnail(_ asset: PHAsset, completion: @escaping ((UIImage) -> Void)) {
        option.isSynchronous = true
        var thumbnail = UIImage()
        manager!.requestImage(
            for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight),
            contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option,
            resultHandler: { (result, _) -> Void in
                thumbnail = result!
                completion(thumbnail)
            })
    }
```

P.S. And I tried use options:

```
option.isSynchronous = false
option.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
```

Comment: What size are you requesting? maybe try lower resolution or `deliveryMode.fastFormat`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62202440/2303865